# Convert flac to lossless wma?

Tags: sound, ffmpeg, convert, avconv

I have a bunch of flac files I have to convert to lossless .wma because a game I have requires I use it.

I was looking at `avconv`, and tried `avconv -i song.flac output.wma`, however I believe this made a lossy output, as its encoder was `Lavc57.25.0 libmp3lame`. I also tried `ffmpeg` but that didn't do anything.

Any suggestions on how do accomplish this? Thank you.

Comment: I believe that at the moment there is no support under Linux for encoding to WMA Lossless. Which game is it?

Comment: @andrew.46 GTA V PC. It doesn't support flacs, and wav is supported but without metadata (which I want my metadata :-) )  Somebody said lossless wma works so I wanted to give it a try. The only Windows tool I could find required payment for converting songs longer than 2min (even though it was marked as 'freeware')

Comment: This post suggests a few more formats: https://www.reddit.com/r/GrandTheftAutoV_PC/comments/32wn99/gta5_custom_radio_supported_audio_formats/ so perhaps mp3 might be worth a shot?